# Aurelia.js inserting CSS class after click and bind just the row clicked

Tags: javascript, aurelia

my code it is working, but I have a bug, because the `repeat.for` all the td change the color, actually I just want to change 1 row change the color, the row I clicked.

someone knows how to fix this in aurelia.

thanks

js:

```
isSelected = false;
new = 'will change the color'; 
changeColor() {
 alert(this.new);
 this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
}
```

css:

```
.is-row-selected {
 background: green !important;
}

.is-row-not-selected {
  background:#f9f9f9 !important;
}
```

html:

```
<script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/bundles/aurelia.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/bundles/babel.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr repeat.for="juice of $items" class="${isSelected ? 'is-row-selected' : 'is-row-not-selected'}" click.trigger="changeColor()">
   <td>${day | dateFormat: 'M/D/YYYY'}</td>
   <td>${time}</td>
   <td>${location}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `isSelected` is a property on each item in `$items`, and `changeColor()` is a function on each item in `$items`, then you need to call the function like this `juice.changeColor()` and you need to use `juice.isSelected` in the class attribute. Also, you need to use `juice.` before all of the properties you are listing in your table, e.g. `${juice.location}`.

You'll need to change your view to look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr repeat.for="juice of $items" class="${juice.isSelected ? 'is-row-selected' : 'is-row-not-selected'}" click.trigger="juice.changeColor()">
   <td>${juice.day | dateFormat: 'M/D/YYYY'}</td>
   <td>${juice.time}</td>
   <td>${juice.location}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, if `changeColor()` is a function on your main VM, and not on each of the items in `$items`, then you'll need to pass the item itself to the function so it knows what to change the `isSelected` property on.

VM:

```
changeColor(item) {
 alert(item.new);
 item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
}
```

And your template:

```
<table>
  <tr repeat.for="juice of $items" class="${juice.isSelected ? 'is-row-selected' : 'is-row-not-selected'}" click.trigger="changeColor(juice)">
   <td>${juice.day | dateFormat: 'M/D/YYYY'}</td>
   <td>${juice.time}</td>
   <td>${juice.location}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Given the code you provided, I can't really say which of these answers is for you, but it should be one of them.